# Prove that there exists a sequence of compact sets $K_1\subset K_2\subset...\subset A$ such that $\mu(A-\cup_{j\ge1}K_j)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be measurable. Prove that there exists a sequence of compact sets $$K_1\subset K_2\subset...\subset A$$ such that $\mu(A-\cup_{j\ge1}K_j)=0$.

---

Here $\mu(A)$ is the Lebesgue measure of the set $A$, and the measure is not necessarily finite. Also $A-B$ means $A$ without $B$.

I'm thinking of the approximation property: $A$ is measurable $\iff$ for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist a close set $F$ and an open set $G$ such that $$F\subset A\subset G$$ and $$\mu(G-F)<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 2):

If $E$ is measurable then
$$m(E)=\sup \{ m(K): K\subset E, K\textrm{ compact}\}$$
Assume that $m(E)<\infty $. For each $n\in\mathbb N$ we can find compact $K_n\subset E$ such that 
$$m(E\setminus K_n)<1/n$$
Then the sequence of sets $E\setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^n K_j$ is decreasing, therefore 
$$m(E\setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j)=\lim_{j\to\infty }m(E\setminus K_j)\leq \lim_{j\to\infty } \frac{1}{j}=0$$

If $m(E)=\infty $ then write $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (E\cap \{|x|\leq n\})$ and apply the above to each $E\cap \{|x|\leq n\}$. I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: But how do we show $K_n$ is increasing? (i.e., $K_1\subset K_2\subset...$)

Comment: It's in your assumption: $K_1 \subset K_2 \cdots$.

Comment: You can just replace $K_n$ by $F_n=\bigcup_{j=1}^n K_j$ which is still compact.